# XSLT choose multiple Elements with key

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML File looking like like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>   
    <Forms name = "Form1">
        <Form ID='allowed'></Form>
        <Form ID='mandatory'></Form>
        <Form ID='not_allowed'></Form>
        <Form ID='choose'></Form>
    </Forms>
    <Forms name = "Form2">
        <Form ID='mandatory'></Form>
        <Form ID='not_mandatory'></Form>
        <Form ID='not_mandatory'></Form>
        <Form ID='not_mandatory'></Form>
    </Forms>
</XML>
```

I want to know all Forms which contain Forms with the ID allowed OR mandatory:

```
<XML>   
    <Forms name = "Form1">
        <Form ID='allowed'></Form>
        <Form ID='mandatory'></Form>
    </Forms>
    <Forms name = "Form2">
        <Form ID='mandatory'></Form>
    </Forms>
</XML>
```

What I have so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:variable name="Form" select = "'allowed'"/>
<xsl:key name="get_Forms_by_ID" match="Forms" use="Form/@ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/XML">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template  match="Forms">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('get_Forms_by_ID', $Form)"></xsl:copy-of>
</xsl:template>
```

My Question is how can I us the key function with the a multiple value variable $Form: allowed or mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(For XSLT 2.0) define your variable as a *sequence*:

```
<xsl:variable name="Form" select = "('allowed', 'mandatory')"/>
```

---

### Edit:

For XSLT 1.0 , you could use:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="key('get_Forms_by_ID', 'allowed') | key('get_Forms_by_ID', 'mandatory')"/>
```

If you need to predefine the key values in a variable first, you will have to use the EXSLT node-set() extension function to convert them into a node set before you can use them in a (single) key() call.

Comment: I already tried something linke this but it tells me that's an invalid expression. Are there any other solutions i.e. a foreach loop?

Comment: @user3891252 Are you sure you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor? Your stylesheet declares version 2.0.

Comment: ah ok I just saw that python's lxml only supports xslt 1.0... how is the solution for version 1.0?

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: +1 for suggestions to use multi values within variables.